# How to include special chars in REGEXP BINARY mySQL search?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have this regexp in my search and it works fine

searching for:

```
{"id":"9","value":"730,000"}
```

sql regex

```
REGEXP BINARY '(.*{\"id\":\"9\",\"value\":\"730,000\"}.*)'
```

but if I add a dollar or euro sign it cant find it

```
 {"id":"9","value":"$730,000"}
```

Is there a better way to improve this to accept the special chars?

Any help is appreciated.

**P.S. Don't freak out about storing json and me looking for it like this , I have no other way to get it.**

**Update** ,   the field is  **utf8_unicode_ci** which would save this

```
Faugères
```

as this

```
{"id":"11","value":"Faug\u00e8res"}
```